# Filtering measure by dimension causes similar behaviour to IgnoreUnrelatedDimensions = True in calculated member

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssas, mdx, ssas-2008

I'm trying to define a calculated member in SSRS using SSAS that is the sum of a measure filtered on a value of a dimension. This works fine, except when I view the calculated member in the browser by the dimension I filtered on. Instead of seeing `null` values where I would expect them, the grand total is repeated over the rows, similar to what happens when you set `IgnoreUnrelatedDimensions` to `True` on a measure group.

How can I fix this?

Example calculated member defined on the calculations tab in SSRS:

```
AGGREGATE({[Cow].[Hoof Location].[Front]}, [Measures].[Count])
```

This works fine when viewed against anything other than `[Cow].[Hoof Location]`. But when viewed by this dimension, Count is repeated across rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
IIf([Cow].[Hoof Location].CurrentMember IS [Cow].[Hoof Location].[All],
    AGGREGATE({[Cow].[Hoof Location].[Front]}, [Measures].[Count]),
    NULL
   )
```

Possibly you have to adapt the name of the `All` member to the name it has in your cube.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an MDX calculated measure that uses trick that you want:

I used my base, so please substitute `[Create Date].[Create Date].[Year].&[2014]` with your own set and `[Create Date].[Create Date].[Month]` with your level of dimension `[Cow]`. Here is a standard 'Year-Month-Day' dimension.

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[TestAgg]
 AS
    IIF(
        Intersect(
            [Create Date].[Create Date].CurrentMember
            ,Exists(
                Descendants(
                    [Create Date].[Create Date].[Year].&[2014]
                    ,[Create Date].[Create Date].[Month]
                    ,SELF_BEFORE_AFTER
                )
            )
        ).Count > 0
        ,[Measures].[Count]
        ,IIF(
            [Create Date].[Create Date].CurrentMember is [Create Date].[Create Date].[All]
            ,AGGREGATE(
                {[Create Date].[Create Date].[Year].&[2014]}
                ,[Measures].[Count])
            ,null
        )
    ),
VISIBLE = 1;
```

Here is some explanation:

1. I used `Descendants` to organize the set of necessary members.
2. `Intersect` is used to understand whether the current member of the dimension is under this filter condition.
3. Then the first `IIF` is used to show blanks in other years.
4. The last `IIF` is used for the total.

And some pictures of this measure's behavior:

[image: Days]

[image: Months]

[image: Years]

If you want the same value on each level of 2014 and its children (but blanks for others), use

```
AGGREGATE(
    {Exists(
        Descendants(
            [Create Date].[Create Date].[Year].&[2014],
            [Create Date].[Create Date].[Month],
            AFTER)
        )
    },
    [Measures].[Count]
)
```

or `SUM`. But I guess it will look like `IgnoreUnrelatedDimensions=True` for this member and children, as you said before.

One more tip: if there is a filtering on another levels you can play with `Descendants` levels and flag parameter (`AFTER`, `BEFORE`, `SELF_AND_AFTER` etc.)
This article can help to understand this technique: http://www.sqllion.com/2011/08/mdx-descendants/

Hope this will help to solve the problem.

**UPDATE**
For the lowest level it's better to use `Ascendants` like this:

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[TestAgg2]
 AS
    IIF(
    Intersect(
        [Create Date].[Create Date].CurrentMember,
        Exists(
            Ascendants([Create Date].[Create Date].[Day].&[20140214])
        )
    ).Count > 0,
    (
        [Create Date].[Create Date].[Day].&[20140214],
        [Measures].[Count]
    ),
    IIF(
        [Create Date].[Create Date].CurrentMember is [Create Date].[Create Date].[All],
        AGGREGATE(
            {[Create Date].[Create Date].[Day].&[20140214]},
            [Measures].[Count]
        ),
        null
    )
),
VISIBLE = 1;
```